# Vue.js v-show and v-else not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't seem to get `v-show` and `v-else` to work. The documentation says:

> The `v-else` element must following immediately after the `v-if` or `v-show` element - otherwise it will not be recognized.

**Documentation**: http://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-show

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/p2ycjk26/2/

Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="test in tests" v-show="tests.length">
            <td>{{ test.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-else>
            <td>No data available in table</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el: 'table',

    data: {
        tests: [{
            name: 'Testing'
        }, {
            name: 'Testing 2'
        }, {
            name: 'Testing 3'
        }]
    }
});
```

It's probably something simple but I can't quite figure it out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like `v-for` and `v-else` don't work together well. I would place the condition higher up (on the `<tbody>`) and use `v-if` instead (that way, you wont have two `<tbody>` elements):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-if="tests.length">
        <tr v-for="test in tests">
            <td>{{ test.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody v-else>
        <tr>
            <td>No data available in table</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p2ycjk26/4/

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I suppose I'll post an issue on the Vue.js GitHub repo and see what they say but this is a nice workaround, thanks.

Comment: I think that the issue lies in the repetitive nature of `v-for`, so that possibly the context of the `v-show` is lost. But let us know here if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else)

> A *v-else* element must immediately follow a *v-if* or a *v-else-if* element - otherwise it will not be recognized.

Also see [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

> Note that *v-show* doesn’t support the `<template>` syntax, nor does it work with *v-else*.

Comment: It looks like it worked (or was meant to) in version 1.x, and was removed in 2.0. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2639